# Mixer-audio card-notebook recording problem

Tags: recording

Xonar U7 works perfect at home, where I use my desktop headphone as a source of sound and set it at line-in. I use a recently purchased Lenovo notebook with Intel i5 to record a powerpoint presentation with voice-over and for a software, I use Movavi Screen capture Studio. The problem arises when I bring that recording equipment to my church and plug a cable from the church mixer's line output into Xonar's mic-in. I believe the only available output with no mark has line-level, as I have recorded, with no trouble at all, my preaching with Zoom H2, connecting to its marked line-in jack. Xonar however doesn't give me line-in option, so I have no choice but to choose mic-in. I disable Lenovo's system mic, but cannot stop all the noises outside coming into my recordings, and the recording of my preaching itself is almost unrecognizable, as if the church mixer's output is mic-level rather than line-level. Overall the quality of sound is terrible. I tried tweaking around the equipment but after all could make it work.

Comment: This question is very confusing as it stands. Could you possibly re-write it or at least try to tidy it up a bit so It is more understandable? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , check your cables at the church, secondly check your drivers / software etc.

Maybe consider buyng a cheap card with some real jack mic/line input.

I think you should be ok recording the line in signal if everything else i mentioned is ok (cabling & software) but in no means this is a hi end format.

Also be sure to use the right output from your card , use the buttons to give some gain to the sound.

Comment: Thank you very much for your expert advice. Myself I'm a real novice in this field. Actually I suspected there's something wrong about the cable. Would you please specify what may be wrong in cabling. I have no idea at all.

Comment: Could be so many things when you take the output of a mixer !! Cable should be 3,5" jack , if you can't guarantee that it's in working state buy a new one ! The troubleshooting is simple , you start by ruling out things that work and end up with the problem ..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing and seems to contradict itself, but I'll try to answer with a quick, general reply.

It sounds like your equipment is being overloaded by the line level signal comming from the church mixer. Are you sure the Xonar's input is set to line-level?

Maybe the church mixer is a powered mixer?